# Apache2 - Only allow .pdf and index access in WebDAV

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, webdav

I've set up a `WebDAV` with apache2 in order to use it with Zotero. As we only want to upload and download pdfs over this webdav, I want to prevent the upload or download of any other files than pdf files. For this, I have used:

```
<Location *>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName DAV
        AuthUserFile "*"
        Require valid-user
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule !(\.pdf)$ - [F,NC] # only allow access to pdf to prevent misuse
</Location>
```

This works fine until Zotero checks whether you have access to the DAV which it checks by calling the base URL, so e.g. `bla.com/zotero`. With this configuration, the user is not allowed to visit the DAV index. How do I need to change my `RewriteRules` in order to only allow pdf files and the directory index? I've tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and some other stuff, but that didn't work, still 403 for the index.

Due to our setup, the `FilesMatch` directive does not seem to work, so we have to stick with `RewriteRules` for now.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: To clarify, `/zotero` is a physical directory? Presumably the request is therefore `/zotero/` (with a trailing slash)? Do you have a file that generates the "DAV index"? like `index.html` or `index.php` or are you relying on Apache generating this index with mod_autoindex?

Comment: @MrWhite The url is https://abc.def.com/g/h/zotero and the according physical directory is /var/www/g/h/zotero. The request can either be g/h/zotero or g/h/zotero/, so with or without a trailing slash. There is no index file, apache is generating the index. So allowed requests should be abc.def.com/g/h/zotero , abc.def.com/g/h/zotero/, abc.def.com/g/h/zotero/[*].pdf, everything else should result in a 403.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` ...

Directives in a server (or vHost) context execute *before* the request has been mapped to the filesystem, so the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable does not yet contain the filesystem path that the URL maps to (it simply contains the URL).

To check the filesystem path in a server context (whether it maps to a file or directory), you need to use a look-ahead instead. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !(\.pdf)$ - [F,NC,NS]
```

NB: Be careful of line-end comments; they are not supported by Apache.

The `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive is required to prevent subrequests from being blocked. When mod_autoindex generates the directory listing it also makes additional subrequests on each file in the directory in order to fetch the file size and last modified timestamps etc. You need to prevent your mod_rewrite check being triggered on these subrequests.

> **UPDATE:** With the NS flag and *without* lookahead, it seems to work! But why is that the case? As you explained, lookahead should be necessary?

If these directives are actually inside a `<Directory>` or `<DirectoryMatch>` container (in other words they are in a *directory* context, the same as `.htaccess`) then you will need to use the plain `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable, without the look-ahead.

This would also seem to be consistent with the output you are seeing in the server log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I have tried the look-ahead solution (and removed the line-end comment) and I still get a 403 when opening the index :/

Comment: When you remove these mod_rewrite directives completely then the index is accessible?

Comment: Indeed it is available as soon as I remove the directives. So somehow, the condition does not apply :/

Comment: Ah, you will also need the `NS` flag on the `RewriteRule`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but I still receive a 403 error, even with the NS flag. Maybe you've got another idea? Would be awesome!

Comment: For debug purposes, here's the rewrite log: https://pastebin.com/HPR0K2bM

Comment: I think the issue lies somewhere here: 'path=/var/www/bla1/bla2/zotero/ var=REQUEST_FILENAME -> val=/var/www/var' Why does the val get set to /var/www/var? Of course this is not a directory because /var/www/var does not exist. This is strange.

Comment: Funny: With the NS flag and *without* lookahead, it seems to work! But why is that the case? As you explained, lookahead should be necessary? Can you figure out what is going on here :)?

Comment: Curious. Where are these directives exactly? Are they in a `<Directory>` container? I had assumed these directives were directly in a _server_ (or _virtualhost_) context. However, if they are in a _directory_ context (`<Directory>` or `<DirectoryMatch>` container) then you will indeed need to use the plain `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable.